# How to install Passenger 3.0.11 with Apache2 on Ubuntu 11 (on VPS Server)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, apache2, passenger, vps

Seeking help on passenger install.

I have VPS with Ubuntu 11 pre-installed with it. Rails (Rails 2) app and gems and all rubies are installed under user `xuser` that is also added to sudoers.

I've successfully installed passenger 3.0.11 `home/xuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/passenger-3.0.11`

But, I need to bind passenger with Apache2, so when i'm trying to do it:

```
passenger-install-apache2-module
```

I'm getting stuck with this message

```
[rake aborted! Command failed with status (1): [g++ -Iext -Iext/common -Iext/libev -fPIC -...]
```

Can anyone help and explain what does it mean and what would be a solution for this problem?

Comment: Post the complete error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing apache passenger module by 'apt-get install libapache2-mod-passenger'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but I could fix upgrading ruby from 2.0.0-p645 to 2.2.2